# strange behavior of selector

Tags: android, android-layout

I want to create layout out with rounded rectangle border with gradient filling color 
so I used the following selector

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

<item>

    <shape>

        <gradient
            android:angle="90"
            android:startColor="#FFFF0000"
            android:endColor="#FF00FF00"
            android:type="linear" />

        <padding android:left="7dp" android:top="7dp" 
            android:right="7dp" android:bottom="7dp" /> 

        <corners android:radius="4dp" /> 

    </shape>

</item>

</selector>
```

and the layout look like this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"  android:background="@drawable/buttonsborder">


</LinearLayout>
```

but it doesn't fill all the sc reen only the controls I put on the layout , any idea how to make the selector fill the whole layout even if there's no controls

Comment: Perhaps, android:layout_height="**fill_parent**"

Comment: make layout hieght fill_parent and than try

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your layout height to `fill_parent` .

Answer (score 1):

plz

use this in an xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:shape="rectangle" >
<gradient
    android:angle="225"
    android:endColor="#FF0E2E57"
    android:paddingLeft="20dip"
    android:startColor="#FF0E2E57" />

<corners
    android:bottomLeftRadius="40dp"
    android:bottomRightRadius="40dp"
    android:paddingLeft="20dip" 
    android:topLeftRadius="40dp"
    android:topRightRadius="40dp"/>
```

and use this as your background. in layout

Answer (score 0):

Hi use this xml for rounded rectangle borders and then set it  in android:background

```
<
?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
        <item>        
            <shape>
                <gradient
                    android:endColor="#ffffff"
                    android:startColor="#ffffff"
                    android:angle="270" />
                <stroke
                    android:width="0.5dp"
                    android:color="#808080" />
                <corners
                    android:radius="10dp" />
                <padding
                    android:top="10dp"
                    android:bottom="10dp"
                    android:left="10dp" />
            </shape>
        </item>
    </selector>
```